# How to have coins burst out in random directions after destroying an object in unity?

Tags: unity, 2d

I want coins to burst out of an obstacle in random directions after I destroy it, kind of like the rings in sonic. I have everything else done: the physics, bouncing, instantiating to coins. I just don't know how to get them to fly out in random directions.

Here's my script:

```
while (counter < 5) {
    counter++;
    Instantiate(token, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
Destroy (gameObject, 0.4f);
```

Comment: The rings in sonic weren't random. They were spawned in a circle, and depending on the number of rings (up to some maximum, obviously less then 100) multiple concentric circles were created.

Comment: It might be worth a shot to create a particle system that solves your problem. I believe there is a collider box that could be used to re-collect the coin after they shot out

Comment: You can try adding impulse type force in random direction right after they are instantiated.(I'm assuming they are rigidbodies)

Answer (score 5):

Unity has a great Random property called `UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle` that will pick a random vector inside the unit circle. It great to assign both position around the spawn point and a random direction they can go in.

An example of a basic trajectory code:

```
void Start()
{
    trajectory = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle * velocity;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position += trajecotry * Time.deltaTime - 2 * gravity * Time.deltaTime**2
}
```

This probably isn't the best example, but the key is how to assign the random trajectory.

Comment: could you give an example of how I could assign it please?

Comment: Just assign it to wherever you assign your initial trajectory. Comments suck for posting code, so I'll post something as an edit.

Comment: I'm trying different versions of it and the best I'm getting is that the coins spawn from position 0, all in the same spot

Comment: @Jordan on Start() do `transform.position += trajectory;` and you'll get the object started from a position around the startup position. Scale the trajectory value if needed.

Comment: ok I got it to spawn in the right place, but they still just spawn in the same position of the obstacle instead of bursting out

Answer (score 0):

I did this to instantiate multiple coins in random directions :

```
Vector3 trajectory = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle * 200f;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rdm_amount; i++)
        {
            GameObject coin = Instantiate(coin_GO, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            coin.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Random.Range(-600f,600f) + trajectory.x, 600f + trajectory.y, Random.Range(-600f, 600f) + trajectory.z);
        }
```